# PATCH Companies using Postman returning 1004: company doesn't exist" error

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge, patch, autodesk-bim360

I'm trying to work out my API connection to PATCH some fields on companies, but every time I sent a PATCH, I get an Error 1004 of "this company doesn't exist."

I can do a GET for the exact same company ID (same account ID, current OATH Bearer with account:write access, etc.) and it returns the full JSON object for the company.

I have tried multiple companies, over multiple weeks, but always have the same problem.

I am following this documentation: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/companies-:company_id-PATCH/

UPDATE: I've been using Postman for my testing, but just tried it in a linux CLI, and was able to successfully update. Must be a problem with some setting in Postman, so I'll keep looking there. Updating Title

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - I had a linefeed/LF/%0A at the end of my URL in Postman that I never noticed.

I'm a complete and total idiot. When I originally pasted in the company ID at the end of the URL, it must have included the linefeed, and I just never noticed it. I had even tried clicking the end of the line, deleting the last character, and re-typing it.

I started digging through the console information on the failed requests, comparing them to my Linux CLI curl that worked. I noticed an extra %0A at the end of what was sent. Deleted the linefeed, and everything works perfectly.

I really hope this helps save someone else frustration in the future.